# Increase thickness of edges in graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-graphs

Consider the following LaTeX code that create  Petersen graph in latex

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90]
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Hasse]
    \SetVertexNormal[LineWidth=.7pt]
    \grPetersen[RA=2.4,RB=1.3]
    \AddVertexColor{red}{a0,b1,b2,a3}
    \AddVertexColor{green}{a1,b0,a4}
    \AddVertexColor{blue}{b4,b3,a2}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How it possible increase  edge thickness of above graph?

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your graph.

Answer (score 1):

The edge thickness is controlled by `\EdgeLineWidth`, with initial value `.8pt`. See the doc of `tkz-graph` package, which is auto loaded by `tkz-berge`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90]
    \renewcommand*{\EdgeLineWidth}{2pt} % default is .8pt
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Hasse]
    \SetVertexNormal[LineWidth=.7pt]
    \grPetersen[RA=2.4,RB=1.3]
    \AddVertexColor{red}{a0,b1,b2,a3}
    \AddVertexColor{green}{a1,b0,a4}
    \AddVertexColor{blue}{b4,b3,a2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```